# Custom post type loops with different page templates

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions, loop, templates

My website has two different page templates. Each page template contains a different custom post type. The posts from the loops can be loaded by `AJAX` to load more.

This is the common code that I run for the two template pages. It includes the loop and I use `is_page_template()` with `PHP` variables to detect which template is in the frontend to load the custom post type `music` or `movies`.

The thing is, my level of `PHP` is basic and I'm not sure if my code is secure or has any breach.

```
<?php
if( is_page_template( 'page-music.php' ) ) :

    $current_post_type = 'music';

elseif( is_page_template( 'page-movies.php' ) ) :
    
    $current_post_type = 'movies';

endif;
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

                <div class="wrapper wrapper-archive flex-cols">
                    <?php
                    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                    $args = array(
                        'post_type' => $current_post_type,
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'posts_per_page' => 4,
                        'paged' => $paged
                    );

                    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'cpt-archive' );

                    endwhile;

                    wp_reset_postdata();
                    ?>
                </div>

                <?php
                if ($loop->max_num_pages > 1) :
                    echo '<button id="load-more-'. $current_post_type .'" class="load-more-archive">Load more</button>';
                endif;
                ?>

                <script>
                    var current_post_type = '<?php echo $current_post_type ?>', 
                    posts_myajax = '<?php echo serialize( $loop->query_vars ) ?>',
                    current_page_myajax = 1,
                    max_page_myajax = <?php echo $loop->max_num_pages ?>
                </script>
                
    </article>
```

Any comments about the code are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have some recommendation maybe could help You and Other

1. for better security and some reason create a plugin for do it and use shortcode or other way for print result in front page
2. don't use ajax call to the direct php file and use admin_ajax.php which you can find how to use in [wp document](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)
3. prevent direct access to php file with this code on the first line of all php files `if(! defined( 'ABSPATH' )){die("You Can not Access Directly to This File")}`
4. Alwayse use [wp-nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) for send and receive any data in wordpress